# How to use a bsoncxx::types::b_oid as the key of a std::map

Tags: mongodb, c++11, stdmap, bson

I'm using bsoncxx to manage data in a MongoDB database.
Consider this declaration in a custom class:

`std::map<bsoncxx::types::b_oid, SomeClassHere> m_Documents;`

The compiler complains: "error C2676: binary '<': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator"

Surprisingly, operator< is declared in oid.hpp:

`friend BSONCXX_API bool BSONCXX_CALL operator<(const oid& lhs, const oid& rhs);`

So, whats wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: b_oid and oid are different types.

Comment: Thanks D. SM, this is the point, and the correct answer !
adding line:
using uint96_t = bsoncxx::oid;
and using uint96_t as the std::map key did the trick.